# How to apt-get install packages on kubernetes for Google cloud composer

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Cloud composer to orchestrate my airflow instance but not sure how to install packages for the airflow worker bash.

Previously I was running airflow on a google compute engine instance using docker, it was easy to specify requirements via the docker make file.

As someone who is new to kubernetes and Cloud composer, I was wondering if there is something similar I could do for kubernetes/Cloud composer as I previously did for docker?

I looking to install `lzop` for unix and also would need to update the gsutil boto config file with s3 credentials.

How do you pull a new docker image into kubernetes and recreate it for pods?

Sorry if my lingo is incorrect, this is new to me

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, if I read the documentation correctly, you cannot modify the images used by Composer. Unless you deploy your custom solution on a Kubernetes cluster, I think you cannot extend it beyond Python Libraries and Airflow Plugins.

You can ssh into each worker Compute Engine instance and install it manually on each machine.

You may try to run `apt` it via `BashOperator`, but I doubt you will succeed; unfortunately, Composer is still a Beta product, and many features are still in the making.

Comment: Thanks, for now I have done apt-get install on each of the worker nodes to get the packages I require and it seems to run most of the time. Good idea on apt-get install in a bash operator. I didn't consider doing this but should a better temp fix

Comment: Manually accessing the various workers' nodes instances works too but is a chore. If you ever try the BashOperator Route let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: I already tried the manual route and installed but seems to sometimes fail still and say package doesn't exist which is weird. Same is now happening with your suggested approach, I wonder if this is because it installs lzop on one node and then try to run lzop from a different node.

Comment: Its more than fine for a temp solution, so appreciate your help. If you can think of anything to do to alleviate the above issue than let me know

Comment: Sure, remember to flag the answer as accepted if you have found it satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then here is my answer.

Kubernetes is an orchestrator for Docker, therefore, in Kubernetes cluster, you can use Airflow images built by you for Docker.

Just build your own image using `docker build <you_Dockerfile>`, push it to your registry, and after that, you can use the image in the section `image: <your_registry>/<your_image>` in Airflow deployment YAML-file for Kubernetes.
Here you can find an example of [Setting Up Apache Airflow on Kubernetes](https://github.com/brunocfnba/Kubernetes-Airflow).

As to Cloud Composer, it is a fully managed workflow orchestration service built **on** Apache Airflow. It is not a tool for managing your Airflow. For more information, you can look through the link, there is a short video with a brief explanation: [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/)

Comment: Artem, appreciate your time but this isn't answering my question

Comment: @D_usv, could you describe in more details, what you want to do?

Comment: I understand the architecture, see  Michele 'Ubik' De Simoni response below. What I'm trying to do is update the docker image on my kubernetes cluster which hosts my airflow. any ideas?

Comment: @D_usv if you want to use new image in Kubernetes Deployment, you need to update field `image: <your_registry>/<your_NEW_image>`. So, for example, you created Docker image `Airflow_with_updates:1.0.0`, now you need to upload it to `<your_registry>`, after that you need to update field image in your Airflow Deployment `image: <your_registry>/Airflow_with_updates:1.0.0`

Comment: thanks for your quick response, where do I edit this?

Comment: @D_usv `kubectl get deployments` - you can check correct name of you deployment. After that, you can run `kubectl edit <your_deployment_name>`, it will open configuration of your deployment in an editor

Comment: I'm getting the error: the server doesn't have a resource type "xxxxx" when I run kubectl edit <deployment_name>. I've also tried doing it at the pod and node level and am getting the same error

Comment: @D_usv sorry, `kubectl edit deployment <your_deployment_name>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173341/discussion-between-d-usv-and-artem-golenyaev).